# Change name File selected by input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change name's file selected by `input type=file`, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('body').on('change', '#FileID', function() {
    var name = document.getElementById('FileID');
    name.files.item(0).name = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    console.log('Selected file: ' + name.files.item(0).name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='FileID' class='class1' type='file' name='Images' value='' />
```

Comment: You cannot change the filename from JS. Assuming that your goal is to save the file with a different name on the server, you will have to do that to the copy you receive on the server when the request is sent

Comment: You can't change the filename by using js. If you change the filename using `js` it may cause to generate an error `(file not found or something like that)` after form submission. You can rename the file at the time of uploading in destination folder, depend on what programming language do you use.

Comment: Question: *why* do you want to change the `input type=file`'s file name? What are you trying to achieve by changing this?  Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) The reason it's blocked is for security, to stop malicious websites doing something like: - set file to c:\password.txt - upload file - in a hidden iframe.

Comment: @raptor, what is the purpose behind renaming? BTW, files can be renamed on server side as well.

Comment: This link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48453136/1666800

Answer (score 3):

To change the name of a File object, you need to create a new `File` instance.
You can create one from a previous File object and it will act a simple wrapper over the data on disk.

The sketchier part is to update the `<input type="file">` value to use this new File.
It is now possible through an hack as exposed in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47172409/3702797):

```js
$('body').on('change', '#FileID', function(evt) {
  const newName = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
  const input = evt.currentTarget;
  const previousFile = input.files[0];
  const newFile = new File([previousFile], newName);
  
  // hack to update the selected file
  const dT = new DataTransfer();
  dT.items.add(newFile);
  input.files = dT.files;
  console.log('Selected file: ' + input.files.item(0).name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='FileID' class='class1' type='file' name='Images' value='' />
```

However since this part is still mainly an hack, I can't really recommend its use.
So **if you don't need to show the updated value in the native input, don't do it.** Simply update a custom UI, and use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/) to upload to your server. The last param of `FormData#append(blob, fieldname, filename)` will set the filename sent by the browser in the form-data request:

```js
const form = new FormData();
const file = new File(["some data"], "originalname.txt");
form.append("fileField", file, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000));
console.log("original file's name: ", file.name);
new Response(form).text()
  .then((content) => console.log("formdata content: ", content));
```

So you should not need the aforementioned hacks at all.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone ending here trying to get rid of the file's name, try converting it to base64. this way it won't have the name attached to it and you could upload it how you want. I will leave a code example using reactJS for this.

1: Here is the input file type calling the onChange event with our function:

```
<input onChange={this.handleBackgroundImagePreview} type="file" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg"></input>
```

2: Then convert that image to base64

```
handleBackgroundImagePreview = (e) =>{
  // Retrieves the selected Image or file
  const file = e.target.files[0]

  //Calling async file reader with a callback
  let fileBase64 = '';
  this.getBase64(file, (result) => {
      fileBase64 = result;
      console.log(fileBase64)
      //In here you could upload to the server the base 64 data as you want
  });
}

getBase64(file, cb) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function () {
      cb(reader.result)
  };
  reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
  };
}
```